# XACML2 Schema Generation Error for .NET - Cannot use wildcards at the top level of a schema

Tags: code-generation, xacml, xacml2

Has anyone been able to successfully generate C# entity classes from XACML2 schema files?  I am getting "Cannot use wildcards at the top level of a schema."  I think this has something to do with xs:any elements.  I have tried change the processContents="skip" (from "lax") but to no avail.  I get this using [WSCF Blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/) as well as [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly for me using the version of xsd.exe that ships w/ VS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problems running the Xacml3 schema through VS2010 XSD.exe, but I do see this "Cannot use wildcards at the top level of a schema" error when trying to process the Xacml2 schema with XSD.

XSD processes the Xacml2 Policy schema with no errors.

XSD reports this wildcard error when processing the Xacml2 Context schema.

The issue appears to be the combination of `##any` and `mixed="true"` in the `xacml-context:AttributeValueType` schema definition.  Other definitions of `AttributeValueType` in Xacml2 Policy schema and Xacml3 use an `xs:complexContent` wrapper around an `ExpressionType` extension, which in turn contains `xs:any` and `xs:anyAttribute` definitions.  The Xacml2 `context:AttributeValueType` does not contain this wrapper.

**Solution:** Remove `mixed="true"` from the Xacml2 `xacml-context:AttributeValueType` definition and XSD will generate the correct class types for the schema. The generated `AttributeValueType` class will have properties for a list of elements and a list of attributes, which covers all the bases.